# Relational database created/stored on client

Tags: sql, node.js, electron, relational-database, knex.js

I'm in the early stages of designing an Electron application that needs to be able to dynamically generate/access/modify data in a relational structure, stored completely locally. I'm hoping to find a Node package/library that can handle this, without interfacing with any external software that the user would need to download separately.

So far in my research of Node-SQL integrations I've found [Knex.js](https://knexjs.org/) — could it handle something like this?

Comment: In java there are three embedded databases (off the top of my head) that are fully included in the driver itself (H2, Derby, HyperSQL) but I'm curious if a similar solution exists for nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite3 might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I was just looking at this and I think it might work! Do you have any suggestions for a JS library implementation? So far I've found [better-sqlite3](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3)